# Algebraic values of the Gamma function using $\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, transcendental-numbers

Is there any $x\in(0,1)\cap\mathbb Q$ different from $1/2$ such that $\Gamma(x)$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q(\pi)$?

Comment: Technically, this is an open question. Practically, no one expects it to be the case. Basically, all factorials or $\Gamma$ functions of argument $\dfrac1a$ are related to geometric shapes determined by algebraic equations of the form $x^a+y^a=r^a$.